# advancedSlider Image Slider Plugin Integration Issue with thumbnails.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an Image slider called [Advanced Slider](http://codecanyon.net/item/advanced-slider-jquery-xml-slider/132618) integrated to my site.Which looks something like [image: this] Unfortunately at the time of item posting I didn't make image thumbnails specifically. Is there anyway to show images by limiting image height or some css magic in this slider so that images are not cropped in thumbnails. [This is link to my slider page](http://104.238.102.6/~zerobytes/blue_lizard_audio/index.php/items/item_detail/pi5aLKd9E86)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this in your thumbnail class:

```
.thumbnail{  
    ....
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: @ Nacho Ramos Sánchez . Thankyou very much. it did the job perfectly. I have pushed the code. You can view it . Thanks again. Marking this thread as answered